# AVFoundation - Video didn't play in AVMutablecomposition with AVplayer

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation, avplayer, avmutablecomposition

I am working on playing a online video file with AVplayer using AVMutablecomposition. The Video plays very fine when I play it on browser but I just cant get it play on my iPad.

Here's the code:

```
self.composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

NSURL *urlVideo = [NSURL URLWithString:@"{video location}"];
AVURLAsset *videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:urlVideo options:nil];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

NSError *error = NULL;

AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]objectAtIndex:0];
CMTimeRange x = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [videoAsset duration]);
[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:x ofTrack:videoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
```

And the code to set the AVPlayer:

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:composition];

 self.player = [[AVPlayer alloc]initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
AVPlayerLayer *layerVideo = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player];
layerVideo.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
layerVideo.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
layerVideo.position = CGPointMake(1024/2, 768/2-10);

[self.view.layer addSublayer:layerVideo];
[self.player play];
```

If I use "AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:videoAsset];" instead of "AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:composition];" then I can see the video playing.

Anyone know how to play the video using AVplayer with AVMutablecomposition ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code lacks a couple error checkings but it works as is.

Unless you're in an iPad this line will send the player off-screen:

```
layerVideo.position = CGPointMake(1024/2, 768/2-10);
```

If that's the case, try with the right position.

Comment: Thanks but in fact in my deployment I added a bg color to layerVideo and I can see that the layer has been added to the screen (without the video playing)

Comment: You can see the background color and still the video may be off screen. Try using a video w/ audio or add a border to the layer (to check that the whole layer is on screen). The code you posted works fine in iOS 5.